# p:lineChart if value start in the middle label points not displayed properly

Tags: java, javascript, primefaces

I used PrimeFaces LineChart. It works properly when all values are available but if there is no item one of the x-axes values(months). One of the series doesn't have item in the first two month and there is in third month. It shows its label points not properly. Items value for March displayed in March correctly but its label points displayed in february which is wrong. How to handle this issue I couldn't find solution through web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to handle this issue in time you are creating the series. Simply check if the item has all attributes needed or isn't null. Series has to contain only valid data in time they are loaded to LineChart by Primefaces.

Comment: I've already initialized them but what I need is if there is no item in that month don't display any info on that x-axes and start the line chart on related month on x-axes.( xValues.set("January", (x1 != 0) ? x1: null);) @klimpond

Comment: It is the null, which is causing the problem. Series are just x and y coordinates rendered into a chart. That's why you shouldn't pass the null value to it. You have to miss the January month out or try compute a mean value between December and February or what so ever. I think you can not solve your problem in way of having x value set a no y associated to it. Sorry if I'm wrong, but according to my experience this is the only solution.

Comment: In my method I have two series so the first series have values for first three months but second series has only one value for March. But it doesn't recognize which label belogs to which value. It just fill the chart acording to physical order.It should recognize which y-axes value belogs to which x-axes value.These values are results of customer survey so I need to get each points for related months. Is it not possible to have space between months in multiple series? @klimpond

Comment: I tried to implement your case for dummy data and it seems, that Primefaces Chart's have problems with matching x coordinates when type of String. But when I used `Integer.valueOf(numberOfMonth)` everything worked fine. Try to contact Primefaces developers or raise an Issue in their bug tracker to solve this out. Don't know if this is solution for you to use Integer values for month in your chart, but it is a fix and go solution.